# Android - Returning intent for onActivityResult

Tags: android

I am very new to android and I'm having massive amounts of trouble with using intents, so apologies if this may seem like a noob question. I cannot for the life of me find a solution online.

Basically, I am unsure of how to return the result of an intent back to the activity that called it.

A summary of what my code is intended to do at current time:

1. Activity A calls activity B
2. Activity B calls the gallery to get an image
3. Gallery opens, lets you pick an image
4. Gallery closes
5. Activity B takes the image, and packages it as the result of the intent from A
6. Activity B closes
7. Activity A now has the image (which it then passes again... don't judge me on the merits of doing it that way)

However, at current time it seems to never actually pass the image down.

I am trying to use the setResult() method along with the finish() method to get this done, but it isn't working.

Code A:

```
public class LoadImage extends Activity {

Bitmap loadedImage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_load_image);
 getIntent();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
 // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
 getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.load_image, menu);
 return true;
}

public void sendBackIntent() { //send the loaded image back to the main interface
 Intent data = new Intent();
 data.putExtra("image", loadedImage);
 if (getParent() == null) {
     setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
 }
 else {
     getParent().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
 }
 finish();
}

public static final int GALLERY_LOAD = 1;

public void galleryLoad(View view) { //load an image from the gallery
 Intent galleryLoadIntent = new Intent(this, GalleryLoad.class);
 startActivityForResult(galleryLoadIntent, GALLERY_LOAD);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

    switch(requestCode) {
    case GALLERY_LOAD:
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
         loadedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getParcelableExtra("data");
         sendBackIntent();
         }
     break;
    }
}
}
```

Code B:

```
public class GalleryLoad extends Activity {

// initialise storage bitmap
private Bitmap loadedImage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery_load);
    loadFromGallery();
    finish();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
 // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
 getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.load_image, menu);
 return true;
}


public static final int SELECT_PHOTO = 1;

public void sendBack() {
 getIntent();
 Intent data = new Intent();
 data.putExtra("image", loadedImage);
 if (getParent() == null) {
     setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
 }
 else {
     getParent().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
 }
}

public void loadFromGallery() {
 Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
 photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
 photoPickerIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
 startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

    switch(requestCode) {
    case SELECT_PHOTO:
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){  
            Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            InputStream imageStream;
         try {
             imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
             loadedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
             sendBack();
         } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
     break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

So I guess the question is... how do I get the intents to return back to the previous activity correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with, you're using [`putExtra`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20android.os.Parcelable%29) almost correctly, but are missing the full package name (look at the examples they're using at the link I provided. The example states

> for example the app com.android.contacts would use names like "com.android.contacts.ShowAll".

)

In your case you'd exchange both the name of the package and the name for the data you're passing, which I guess would be "image" for now, so `com.android.contacts.image` if you were using the same package as the example.

On the receiving end you wrote

```
 loadedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getParcelableExtra("data");
```

which would be plain wrong. You need to use the same name you used to "send" the data, so

```
 loadedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getParcelableExtra("image");
```

should be better. But, if you change the name around like the documentation tells you to, you need to add the package as well. Following the example it should be

```
 loadedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getParcelableExtra("com.android.contacts.image");
```

Mind you: change the package names before you implement the changes!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I made your changes and it worked; however, I encountered a new problem where the bitmap was too big (which Asheesh made me aware of) to travel through intents. I ended up turning it into a byte stream so it'd be compressed.

Comment: Glad to be of service! I actually implemented something similar myself; since I'm only using one image at a time, I was able to use a "universal" file which I store in the SD card and access anywhere. Still, it wouldn't hurt if you'd look up the tutorials for Android on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with your code is you are try to pass Bitmap by putExtra method which is not possible, you can pass Bitmap by putParcelableExtra but I will not suggest you because if the image is too big it will crash your app. So according to me you just pass the URI that  you are getting in onActivityResult and Activity A recreate the image if you want or you can just passed it along